# How to restrict autos scanning of src/test/java in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-test

I have created a simple web app by following the book "Mastering Spring MVC". Everything was working fine, however, during the testing chapter, I have created two beans with @Primary annotation. 1. ProviderSignInController and 2. An Impl of my search service class. Both of these are in package src/test/java.

The problem here is that if I deploy my application, even then, these two beans come into the picture and I am not able to work with my actual authentication and search service.

I am not getting any error or exception. I would like to know what could be the best way to automatically inject my mocks/stubs while testing and actual implementations when I deploy the app in my dev environment.

The source code link is [here](https://github.com/yasin3061/masterSpringMvc). Thanks.

Comment: This implies that there is a bug in your build process.

Classes from the src/test/java directory should not be included in the result of a package goal.

This will not happen in a normal maven build.

Comment: I am using Gradle. I will check on that. I have not done any specific configurations to avoid tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the way I was executing the application.

When I launched the application directly from eclipse (Run As Spring Boot App), the tests were included in the build as they were present in the classpath.

I modified my approach and now I am using gradle build (gradle bootRun) to launch my app. This solves the problem. Thanks to @DwB for providing the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `@Primary`, I'd suggest using `@Profile("PRODUCTION")` along side `@Bean` for your real/production beans/classes & `@Profile("!PRODUCTION")` with your test beans/classes. Then, specify the active profile(s) at runtime

`-Dspring.profiles.active=PRODUCTION, ...`